# how do I make a wind that pushes a player in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a wind that slowly blew the player off the platform.

I have been looking for a long time how to make a wind that blew the player away, but I found visual effects or broken scripts that I cannot fix due to my inexperience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create wind in unity you can use the AreaEffector2D component. I recommend watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgUqhsAzGWs&ab_channel=Unity) as it explains how the component works in details and with an example. You should also check the [AreaEffector2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AreaEffector2D.html) documentation on the unity documentation website.

Hopefully this fixes your problem